# random.seed AttributeError: module 'random' has no attribute 'randrange'

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I found errors to this script. I have no idea why, because the standard module / lib supposed to be exist by default. This is the snippet.

```
#!/usr/bin/python -u
import random
import string

flag = "FLAG:"+("fffaa\n")[:-1]
enkripflag = ""
random.seed("random")
for c in flag:
    if c.islower():
        enkripflag += chr((ord(c)-ord('a')+random.randrange(0,26))%26 + ord('a'))ord('a'))
```

full : https://gist.github.com/0x4164/797ead20f512241723ea66a3a8fcbafa

The error occured when executing random.seed() & random.randrange()

stacktrace :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "random.py", line 2, in <module>
    import random
  File "/media/data3/play/pucc/random.py", line 10, in <module>
    random.seed(1)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'seed'
```

Comment: What is `c`? Also, `random.seed()` usually takes in an integer, although when I assigned `c='b'` I did not get an error with this code snippet.

Comment: "Error occurred": share the full stack trace.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi shared

Comment: Looks like you have a `random.py` in your project that hides the correct random module when you import. Rename random.py to something else.

Answer (score 0):

Like Pranav said, it is because the filename.
The problem is too obvious. The file has same name as the module, which is the root cause.